# Finding a record in a hash in minions = Minion.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hash

```
minions = Minion.all
```

Is there a way to find minions direct in the variable instead of searching through the database?

I'm trying to clean this up and this would be one way forward I think:

```
subtotal = 0.0
units = Unit.all
self.quote_items.order("area_id").each do |item|
  subtotal += Unit.find(item.unit_id).highest_price(package)*item.quantity if item.unit
end
sprintf("%.2f", Quote.add_margin(subtotal))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you can use the `find` method on the `units` array.

```
subtotal = 0.0
units = Unit.all
self.quote_items.order("area_id").each do |item|
  if unit = units.find{|u| u.id == item.unit_id
    subtotal += unit.highest_price(package)*item.quantity
  end
end
sprintf("%.2f", Quote.add_margin(subtotal))
```

But in this case you can use `:include`. This will load the `item.unit` for each item.

```
quote_items.order("area_id").include(:unit).each do |item|
  if item.unit
    subtotal += item.unit.highest_price(package) * item.quantity
  end
end
```